# Remote Access from Windows to Ubuntu Server with mstsc.exe easy-going?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, remote-desktop, remote-access

I installed for testing win server 2008 and its really easy to get remote access. Just enable RA with one click and then im able to get access with my win 7 with mstsc.exe - IF I would install a linux server, lets say ubuntu server because I heard its the easiest for newbies like me, can I get remote access that easy too with mstsc? Would everything work that easy? I just ask, because if its a big act and its that hard, its maybe not a good idea to play around with a linux server.

Comment: agree with $UtahJarhead. if you would like to get some linux experience, maybe installing a desktop vm on your windows machine to try your hand at the command line in a more friendly environment before moving to a server.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to the wrong tool with Linux.  With Linux, and assuming you're booting to a graphical interface like `gnome`, `kde`, or `xfce`, you will want to use a VNC client.  It's similar to `mstsc.exe`, but a bit more widely adopted.

On a side note, Ubuntu Server by default does not come with a graphical interface, so you would be relegated to using a Command Line Interface (`CLI`) over `ssh` or something similar.  `ssh` is the standard.  Everything in Linux can be maintained over a command line.